# JavaScript - Read XML Document

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Youtube video ID and I want to get the video title for this ID. I've gotten the XML feed that contains the title, but am unsure how to extract it.

[Sample of XML output](http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vnUwxDhE1kU)

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' + videoId
}).done(function ( data ) {
    console.log( data.title ); //does not work
    console.log( data.entry.title ); //does not work
});
```

Comment: You looking for `data.getElementsByTagName("title")[0]`? It's XML!

Comment: @Bergi I noticed when I went `console.log(data.getElementsByTagName("title")[0])`, the output is `<title type="text">TITLE OF VIDEO</title>`. Would it be possible to remove the title tag?

Comment: @Bergi Why can't I do `data.title` with XML? Where would I be using `data.title`?

Comment: No, the output is the whole `<title>` *element* - not a string. You can get the text via `.firstChild.nodeValue`

Comment: Try `console.log(data)` - it will show you an XML *Node* of type `Document` - and that just has no `title` property

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery wont automatically convert XML to JSON for you. Simply use jQuery to treat the XML document as a DOM tree.

```
$(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vnUwxDhE1kU',
        dataType: 'xml'
    }).done(function (data) {
        console.log('done', $(data).find('entry > title').text());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get in the data argument is an XML document. JQuery will also help you to get the info you need in an easier way. The following code works:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/vnUwxDhE1kU'
}).done(function ( data ) {
    var $xml = $(data);
    console.log($xml.find('title').text());
});
```

See this link: http://tech.pro/tutorial/877/xml-parsing-with-jquery for more details.